# E/PdfViewerActivity: fetchFile:file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file does not exist

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open a pdf after creating it via an intent.  The file exists and is readable but save inside the apps directory.

Currently the file is saved in the following manner

```
        OutputStream out;
    try {
        //TODO: expose through a content provider
        out = mContext.openFileOutput(outputFileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        document.writeTo(out);
        out.close();
```

and the file is sent to an intent with the following code

```
    final Intent viewIntent = new Intent();
    viewIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    viewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    mActivity.startActivity(viewIntent);
```

The app trying to open it is the google drive viewer and I see in the Android monitor

> E/PdfViewerActivity: fetchFile:file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file does not exist

This previously worked and I don't think I've changed anything related to this code however I have updated my tooling.  I've tried changing the buildToolsVersion in the build.gradle back to what it was before as well as the support libraries 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+' and 'com.android.support:design:22.+' instead of version 24.2.1

I've tried using the debugger to set the file to be readable just before sending the intent but that did not work.

Thanks

Comment: I think, may be due to permission on os 6.x.

Comment: have you verified that the pdf exists where file path pointed to ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the permissions.
As for the file and the path: I've verified the file exists and that it is readable and has a reasonable size.  I've run the process in the emulator and pulled the file from the device monitor and was able to open it on the computer.

Comment: Didn't see a permission that I could recognize as related...

Comment: having same problem since moving my code to api 23 on marshmallow, worked before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer starting with the [Android 7 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perm) documentation.  Sharing files is no longer allowable when setting MODE_WORLD_READABLE even though the documentation doesn't mention any of this

[image]

I followed the documentation on [sharing files](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) to fix the issue but the sample code in the documentation was more complicated than what I needed.  I still had to add the file provider to the AndroidManifest.xml as well as create the fileprovider.xml.

The resulting code is now

```
    final Intent viewIntent = new Intent();
    viewIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, "my.authority.fileprovider", file);
    viewIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    viewIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");
```